# Magento Go, changing theme CSS to view media storage image?

Tags: css, theme, magento-go

How do I reference a media storage image in a CSS in edit custom.css, so that it overrides the template style. Basically I want to change the colours of the menu bar, but they are not changing. So far my code looks like this:

```
#nav {
background:url("../Headercolourforwebsite.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
min-height: 33px;
padding: 6px 0 0;
text-align: left;}
```

The above gif should change the menu from a black gif to a green gif, with the headercolourforwebsite.gif being stored in the root of media storage.

Is there some special technigue that magento go uses as per the inserting of images as seen below:

```
<img src="{{media url="Headercolourforwebsite.gif"}}" alt="" />
```

I'd be grateful if anyone could assist me. I do not know how to code properly, so I cannot use Magento Community, since my level of understanding of the technology stack is not adequate.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about magento-go, which is closed now

Answer (score 2):

In standard magento there is no way, because the CSS files are not parsed. I have no experience with magento go, but I guess it is here the same.

Therefore you have two possibilites:

1. put the images in the skin dir (if it is possible)
2. use absolute urls

I found more here: http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/image-management-and-uploading/

## Uploading new images from themes

To use the image management tool to insert images in your themes:

1. From the Admin Panel, select your theme and click Customize to go to the Theme Customization page.
2. Click CSS Editor from the left side menu.
3. In the Custom CSS panel, click Manage in the Image Assets field to pop up the image management tool. Important Tip: Images uploaded and used in a theme are not shared with other parts of your Magento Go store. Similarly, images used in CMS pages cannot be reused in your themes – they must be uploaded separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav {
    background:url("../Headercolourforwebsite.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    min-height: 33px;
    padding: 6px 0 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

the background has to be like:

```
url("../css_editor_images/eadercolourforwebsite.gif")
```

Comment: What do you want to say? I don't understand this answer :(